# How to reset default button after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I use jquery to change the button style (bootstrap & fontawesome) during the state. When a button is clicked the button changes to loading. Once the success data responded from ajax. A button is changed to done. But after done, I need the button reset to the default state.

Here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#printBtn button").click(function(){         
            $("#printBtn").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sq-lg disabled"><em class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x"></em><br /><span>Printing...</span></button>');
            setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'inc/prvw_print.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data=='success'){
                            $("#printBtn").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sq-lg"><em class="fa fa-check fa-5x"></em><br /><span>Done</span></button>');
                            setInterval(function() {
                                $("#printBtn").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sq-lg"><em class="fa fa-print fa-5x"></em><br /><span>Print?</span></button>');
                            },500);
                        }else{                      
                            $("#printBtn").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sq-lg"><em class="fa fa-warning fa-5x"></em><br /><span>Error</span></button>');
                    }//if
                }//success
            });//ajax
        },1000);//interval
        });//click
   });//ready
```

I added setInterval in `if(data='success')` again. Hoping it will reset the default button after 0.5sec. But it's not. Example here : https://jsfiddle.net/zdpkv2jh/

Working Update here : https://jsfiddle.net/zdpkv2jh/1/

Comment: Why not add the disabled attribute and then remove it rather than adding it as a class?

Comment: Adding/Removing `disabled` is not change the text & icon.

Comment: tried setTimeout? instead of setInterval

Comment: It keeps switching from `btn-success` to `btn-danger` eternity.

Comment: @Wilf I'm not referring to the class you're adding. I'm referring to the disabled attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mistaking `setInterval` with `setTimeout`, so you are currently making ajax requests every x seconds this way. Here is my suggestion, which won't work on JSFiddle because it does not have the URL you are requesting in your actual application:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#printBtn button").click(function() {
    $("#printBtn").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sq-lg disabled"><em class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x"></em><br /><span>Printing...</span></button>');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == 'success') {
              $("#printBtn").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sq-lg"><em class="fa fa-check fa-5x"></em><br /><span>Done</span></button>');
              setTimeout(function() {
                $("#printBtn").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sq-lg"><em class="fa fa-print fa-5x"></em><br /><span>Print?</span></button>');
              }, 500);
            } else {
              $("#printBtn").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sq-lg"><em class="fa fa-warning fa-5x"></em><br /><span>Error</span></button>');
            } //if
          } //success
      }); //ajax
    }, 1000); //interval
  }); //click
}); //ready
```

Comment: Yep. I would recommend reading the specs for functions you don't have written yourselves. That is if you have not used the functions before

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I just start with jquery.

Comment: @Wilf You're welcome. Check out the JavaScript stuff at Code School, it might turn out to be very useful.

Comment: Magnudae, additional question about this. Why the action is not work when after a button has refreshed???

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#printBtn button").click(function(){ 
            $("#printBtn").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sq-lg disabled"><em class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x"></em><br /><span>Printing...</span></button>');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'inc/prvw_print.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == 'success'){

                            $("#printBtn").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sq-lg"><em class="fa fa-check fa-5x"></em><br /><span>Done</span></button>');

                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $("#printBtn").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sq-lg"><em class="fa fa-print fa-5x"></em><br /><span>Print?</span></button>');
                            }, 500);

                    } else {
                            $("#printBtn").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sq-lg"><em class="fa fa-warning fa-5x"></em><br /><span>Error</span></button>');
                    }//if
                }//success
            });//ajax

        });//click
   });//ready
```